# XSLT multi--pass sorting not working

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to generate a sorted HTML table using XSLT. The table data generates, but when I try to sort the table's rows, the order remains unchanged.

I based my code on the following StackOverflow question/response [xslt sort output xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630259/xslt-sort-output-xml).

Here is the XSLT to generate the table :

```
<xsl:variable name="vPass1">
    <unsortedLines>
        <xsl:for-each select="$customer/task">
            <xsl:variable name="task-code" select="./@code" />
                <xsl:for-each select="/workfile/calendar-list/calendar[@id=$customer/task[@code=$task-code]/consultant/@calendar-id]/items/event[summary=$task-code]">
                    <xsl:variable name="calendar" select="../.." />
                    <xsl:variable name="startdate" select="substring(start/datetime, 1, 10)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="enddate" select="substring(end/datetime, 1, 10)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:variable name="previousevents" select="/workfile/calendar-list/calendar[@id=$calendar/@id]/items/event[$startdate=substring(start/datetime, 1, 10) and summary=$task-code and position() &lt; $position]" />
                    <xsl:if test="not($previousevents or $previousevents='')">
                        <xsl:variable name="work-hour-sum">
                        <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                            <xsl:with-param name="events" select="/workfile/calendar-list/calendar[@id=$calendar/@id]/items/event[$startdate=substring(start/datetime, 1, 10) and summary=$task-code]" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:attribute name="startdate">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$startdate" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="$customer/@id" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="/workfile/query/consultant[@calendar-id=$calendar/@id]/@code" /></td>
                            <td class="startdate"><xsl:value-of select="$startdate" /></td>
                            <td class="day-of-week"><xsl:value-of select="custom-elements/day-of-week[@lang='FR']" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="$task-code" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                    <xsl:text>number</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($work-hour-sum, '#.00')" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </unsortedLines>
    </xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1/*" />
```

The variables and tests (`<xsl:if> ... </xsl:if>`) work fine, and I thought they would detract from the problem I have.

Here is also the code of the sorting template :

```
<xsl:template match="unsortedLines">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="substring(tr/td[@class='startdate'], 9, 2)" />
    </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:template>
```

When I run the code, it will get the data and fill in the table rows fine. But when I apply sorting template, the order remains unchanged.

Received output :

```
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-02</td>
    <td>Lundi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>16.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-17</td>
    <td>Mardi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>4.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-04</td>
    <td>Mercredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>9.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-04</td>
    <td>Mercredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>9.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-06</td>
    <td>Vendredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-01</td>
    <td>Dimanche</td>
    <td>CLD-200</td>
    <td>5.50</td>
</tr>
```

Desired output :

```
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-01</td>
    <td>Dimanche</td>
    <td>CLD-200</td>
    <td>5.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-02</td>
    <td>Lundi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>16.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-04</td>
    <td>Mercredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>9.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-04</td>
    <td>Mercredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>9.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-05</td>
    <td>Jeudi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>6.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-06</td>
    <td>Vendredi</td>
    <td>CLD-150</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>PDI</td>
    <td>2013-12-17</td>
    <td>Mardi</td>
    <td>CLD</td>
    <td>4.00</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake, and how to correct it? Help would be much appreciated.

AntonH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of `<xsl:sort select="substring(tr/td[@class='startdate'], 9, 2)" />` you want `<xsl:sort select="substring(td[@class='startdate'], 9, 2)" />` as you are sorting a sequence of `tr` elements which have `td` child elements.

Comment: It works! Great, thanks! I do have a slight question, though: when I tried to sort on the `<tr>` tag, also containing startdate, it didn't work either. Would you have an idea why? `<xsl:sort select="substring(tr[@class='startdate'], 9, 2)" />`

Comment: @AntonH, for the `tr` you create `<xsl:attribute name="startdate">` so the sort expression should be `<xsl:sort select="substring(@startdate, 9, 2)" />`.

Comment: I understand now. Because I was calling the sorting template with `vPass1/*`, the root element was the `<tr>` tag, and I was still thinking that it was `<unsortedList>`, so I was adding bad info to the XPath expression. Again, many thanks.